# Creating a view with an inner join and multiple select conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm practicing for my internship and I mixed in some baseball as well. Working on a view that will give me things like average and obp. I'm getting an error, can someone tell me what's wrong with my syntax?

```
CREATE VIEW `Master Batter 2009 - 2013` AS 
select (select * from baseball.batting),
(select Sum(H)/Sum(AB) from baseball.batting) as 'Average',
(select (Sum(H)+Sum(BB)+Sum(HBP))/(Sum(AB)+Sum(BB)+Sum(HBP)+Sum(SF))) as 'OBP',
join baseball.master
on baseball.master.playerID = baseball.batting.playerID
where yearID = '2013'
Group By playerID
```

Comment: DO NOT NAME YOUR TABLES IN THIS FASHION. IT WILL DRIVE YOU MAD

Comment: Let's see . . . you have no `from` clause and there are a myriad of other syntactic problems.

Comment: fixed that. What else is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a list of few things that are wrong (some syntactically invalid, some just violations of best practice.)

- using identifiers (e.g. view names) that include spaces, dashes and/or other special characters is syntactically valid, but these are way too problematic to be useful
- the query has no FROM clause (the `JOIN` keyword appears where we expect a `FROM` keyword)
- extra comma following the last item in the SELECT list
- `ON` clause only valid following `JOIN`, which requires a preceding `FROM`
- predicates in `ON` clause reference invalid identifier, `baseball.batting` is not a valid reference to table, view or row source alias (referenced in the FROM clause of the query)
- first item in SELECT list can be a subquery, but the subquery can return at most one column, and return at most one row
- references to `H`, `AB`, `player_id` are all unqualified; best practice is to qualify ALL column references
- identifiers and aliases should be enclosed in backticks, not single quotes

---

I recommend you get a query developed and tested before you preface it with `CREATE VIEW`

Absent table definitions (which columns are in which tables), it's nearly impossible to decipher what you are trying to accomplish.

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT m.player_id         AS `player_id`
     , SUM(b.H)/SUM(b.AB)  AS `Average` 
     , (SUM(b.H)+SUM(b.BB)+SUM(b.HBP))/(SUM(b.AB)+SUM(b.BB)+SUM(b.HBP)+SUM(b.SF))) AS `OBP`
  FROM baseball.master m
  LEFT
  JOIN baseball.batting b
    ON b.player_id = m.player_id
   AND b.yearID = 2013    
GROUP BY m.playerID
```

Note that there are some edge cases you may want to handle... divide by zero, addition of NULL results in NULL, etc.